# How can I accurately detect city names in a character vector in R?

Tags: r, string, maps, character

I have a character vector of names and want to accurately identify whether each element contains a city name. To achieve this, I initially used the code below:

```
 name <- c( "Business Applications for New York" ,"Proprietors' Farm Income in New York" ,"Farm Business (Included in Nonfinancial Corporate and Noncorporate Business Sectors); Nonresidential Structures, Current Cost Basis, Transactions")
library(maps)
city=c()
for (j in 1:length(name)) {
     testresult=c()
     for (i in 1:length(us.cities$name)) {
         testresult[i] = agrepl(us.cities$name[i], name[j], max.distance=3, ignore.case=TRUE,fixed = T)
       }
     if (sum(testresult>0)) {
         city[j]=1
       } else{
           city[j]=0 }
}
city
```

However, this code falsely concludes that all elements in the name vector contain city names. Is there a better way to accurately detect city names within each element of a character vector in R? Your insights and code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One approach in this situation may be to leverage the inherent `state.abb`, which contains the state abbreviations, and remove those from `map`'s dataset `us.cities$name` using `gsub` with `paste(..., collapse = "|")`. Then use `grepl` to see if anything matches:

```
cities_only <- trimws(gsub(paste(state.abb, collapse = "|"), "", us.cities$name))

# See comparison:

   head(us.cities$name)
   # [1] "Abilene TX" "Akron OH"   "Alameda CA" "Albany GA"  "Albany NY"  "Albany OR" 

   head(cities_only)
   # [1] "Abilene" "Akron"   "Alameda" "Albany"  "Albany"  "Albany" 

grepl(paste0(cities_only, collapse = "|"), name)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

# or if you want it 1/0, add `+`:
+grepl(paste0(cities_only, collapse = "|"), name)
# [1] 1 1 0
```

(Note `trimws` trims the white space associated with this `gsub`)